# ServiceStack license error after packaging

Tags: c#, servicestack, ilmerge, smartassembly

In my ServiceStack **client** application, everything was fine until I have tried packaging it with SmartAssembly or ILRepack. There are three DLLs:
(**ServiceStack.Client.dll, ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll, ServiceStack.Text.dll**) 
Which when packed cause my application to crash, no matter whether I use encryption\obfuscation options or just pack them into one EXE. My app is targeting .NET 4.0 (I want to support win XP). Stack trace of the exception is:

```
ServiceStack.LicenseException: Unauthorized access request of a licensed feature. Type: 'AccessToken', Assembly: 'ClientTester.exe', 'My EXE path'
ServiceStack.Net40PclExport.VerifyInAssembly(Type accessType, ICollection`1 assemblyNames)
ServiceStack.LicenseUtils.RequestAccess(Object accessToken, LicenseFeature srcFeature, LicenseFeature requestedAccess)
ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient.ToJson[T](T o)
ServiceStack.EncryptedServiceClient.CreateEncryptedMessage(Object request, String operationName, Byte[] cryptKey, Byte[] authKey, Byte[] iv, String verb)
ServiceStack.EncryptedServiceClient.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, Object request)
```

I can't install the [patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3556) as the installer says that it is blocked or the conditions are invalid. In addition, I am not sure that this patch would help me. Any ideas are welcome.
Sidenote: another ServiceStack application, which uses other ServiceStack DLLs except aforementioned ones works well even when packed.

Comment: Have you added your license key to your `app.config`?

Comment: This is client app and it does not require license (I believe). In addition, as I mentioned the issue appears only if i merge all assemblies into my exe, normally there are no issues.

Comment: @HardLuck can you retry with the latest v4.0.55 packages on [MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet)?

Comment: I'm using the latest packages from MyGet (including the commit where CookieContainer got fixed), or there is another commit now?

Comment: @HardLuck you need to get the latest v4.0.55 again. i.e. delete `/packages`, delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\NuGet\Cache\`, reopen VS Solution and restore NuGet packages so it pulls down the latest version.

Comment: Dropped packages cache and loaded the latest version - still the same

Comment: @HardLuck I'm surprised it's the same error, only other thing I can think of is to register a license key which you can [register in code with option b)](https://servicestack.net/download#register)

Comment: That's really strange and sad at the same time as i haven't exceeded any of free quotas, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the absence of an explicitly installed .NET Framework 4.0 is causing that issue. If I compile the solution for 4.5\4.6 version and pack it - everything is fine. Also compiling and packing it for .NET 4.0 and using it on PC that EXPLICITLY has this version installed works as well